# Having aliases active in a terminal session without using bashrc or bash_profile or bash_aliases?

Tags: bash, shell

This question is an offshoot of my question on [whether there's anything wrong with having aliases on a production server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347095/anything-wrong-with-having-aliases-on-a-production-server).

So I tried creating a shell script with some aliases

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "creating aliases..."
alias f='clear;cd ..;ls;pwd'
alias ff='clear;cd ../..;ls;pwd'
```

Did a `chmod +x al.sh`, and ran the script `./al.sh`, but although the "creating aliases..." statement got printed, none of the aliases worked, because they were obviously active only until the script ran.

So is there a way I can run a script containing the aliases I want, which will remain active as long as the terminal session is active? The basic idea being, not to cause problems for colleagues who use the same server.

Comment: What about sourcing the file when you login?

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` may not be same as `bash`... so as fedorqui suggested, use `source al.sh` or `. al.sh` but remove the shebang line which is anyway ignored by `source`

Comment: The shebang creates a new sub-shell and the aliases are set in that sub-shell. When the script ends the sub-shell ends. And the maybe correctly defined aliases are gone. You can not modify a parent shell from within a sub-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cases when you want to store functions and aliases just for your session, I find it quite useful to have a file with them and sourcing it when I login the server.

So just place it somewhere like:

```
~/nav_alias_file.sh
```

And then just after `ssh`ing the server type:

```
source ~/nav_alias_file.sh
```

Note by the way that, as [Sundeep expressed in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393575/having-aliases-active-in-a-terminal-session-without-using-bashrc-or-bash-profile#comment73848381_43393575), you do not need the shebang in that file.